# how to save a file locally in aws lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

is it possible to save a file locally, wherever the aws lambda is running , and then upload ot the s3 later. I am doing this locally and as the data returned from someApi.GetData get be quite big, is it possible to save it as a text file locally where the lambda would run and then delete it?

```
const fs = require('fs')
const writeStream = fs.createWriteStream('test.txt');
const pathName = writeStream.path;

someApi.GetData('http://example.com')
.then(function(data){
   data.forEach(val => writeStream.write(val));
   writeStream.on('finish', ()=> {console.log('success')});
   writeStream.on('error', ()=> {console.log('error')});
   writeStream.end();
})
.catch(error => console.log(error));
```

Comment: You may try to use [EFS with Lambda](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/using-amazon-efs-for-aws-lambda-in-your-serverless-applications/)

Comment: If you just need to save for the duration of the single Lambda run, you can save to /tmp

Comment: @AnonCoward - thanks , if you don't mind, please share some code sample